# Nodejs + expressjs - pm2 and forever don't work?

Tags: node.js, express, forever, pm2

I want to make an app running forever on my nodejs server. But it does not seem to work with [pm2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2) and [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever).

If I start the app manually:

```
$ npm start

> iot@1.0.0 start /var/www/path/to/myapp
> node ./bin/www
```

I can see the app on my browser successfully.

But with [PM2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2):

```
$ pm2 start /var/www/path/to/myapp/app.js

[PM2] Applying action restartProcessId on app [app](ids: 0)
[PM2] [app](0) ✓
[PM2] Process successfully started
┌──────────┬────┬──────┬───────┬────────┬─────────┬────────┬─────────────┬──────────┐
│ App name │ id │ mode │ pid   │ status │ restart │ uptime │ memory      │ watching │
├──────────┼────┼──────┼───────┼────────┼─────────┼────────┼─────────────┼──────────┤
│ app      │ 0  │ fork │ 29210 │ online │ 0       │ 0s     │ 12.383 MB   │ disabled │
└──────────┴────┴──────┴───────┴────────┴─────────┴────────┴─────────────┴──────────┘
```

I tried with this too:

```
$ cd /var/www/path/to/myapp
$ pm2 start app.js
```

It says that the app is online. But when I try to access the app on my browser: http://127.0.0.1:3000/

I get this error:

> This webpage is not available
>
> ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

With forever:

```
$ sudo forever start app.js
warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms
info:    Forever processing file: app.js
```

But no luck at all.

Any ideas what I have missed?

**EDIT:**

In package.json:

```
{
  "name": "iot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^0.8.7",
    "body-parser": "~1.15.1",
    "connect-mongo": "^1.2.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "express": "~4.14.0",
    "express-session": "^1.13.0",
    "hat": "0.0.3",
    "rand-token": "^0.2.1",
    "method-override": "^2.3.6",
    "mongoose": "^4.5.1",
    "morgan": "~1.7.0",
    "pug": "~2.0.0-beta3",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0"
  }
}
```

If I remove `"scripts"` and run `npm update`:

```
{
  "name": "iot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^0.8.7",
    "body-parser": "~1.15.1",
    "connect-mongo": "^1.2.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "express": "~4.14.0",
    "express-session": "^1.13.0",
    "hat": "0.0.3",
    "rand-token": "^0.2.1",
    "method-override": "^2.3.6",
    "mongoose": "^4.5.1",
    "morgan": "~1.7.0",
    "pug": "~2.0.0-beta3",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0"
  }
}
```

Then I start the app manually again but get an error:

```
$ npm start
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-76-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v5.10.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.3

npm ERR! missing script: start
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
```

Comment: What is the body of `scripts.start` in `package.json`?

Comment: @Nonemoticoner Please see my edit above. thanks. What is `scripts.start` for?

Comment: I meant `start` script. Sorry for oversimplyfying it. Hmm, you start node for a directory but when using forever and pm2 you start from particular file. Dunno, but maybe that's a cause.

Comment: what is the `start` script for?

Comment: what should i put in `start` script?

Comment: Basically you could remove it as scripts are optional. It is only to help the user of your app to easiely run an app i.e. type `npm start` instead of `node ./bin/www`. Also, it runs as batch script as far I remember.

Comment: Back to your issue, it might be some directory confusion (at least that's my only idea about that). I faced smth like that once when attempting to use forever from directory where the main script was placed. You should try running from parent directory i.e. where `package.json` is.

Comment: Man, you've misunderstood me. Removing `start` script will only make you unable to use commend `npm start` and that's it. https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts

Comment: My idea for solution is: Navigate to directory where `package.json` is. Run `forever start path/to/you/app.js`. If doesn't work then I have no clue about that.

Comment: I know why! i generated the app project from the express-generator. and it has a `bin` folder in which it run the app. so I have to `cd bin` then `pm2 start www`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by **express-generator** which I use it to generate my app project!

It has a `bin` folder in which it runs the http. so I have to `cd bin` then `pm2 start www`.

Comment: I think you can squeeze it into one command: pm2 start bin/www (without cd'ing)