# PM2: app can’t be reached (ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED)

Tags: node.js, express, pm2

I have a working Express.js-based app running on Node.js.
Now, I want to wrap it up with **pm2**. To do that, I've defined **ecosystem.json**:

```json
{
    "apps": [
        {
            "env": {
                "NODE_ENV": "development",
                "PORT": "3000"
            },
            "env_production": {
                "NODE_ENV": "production"
            },
            "exec_mode": "cluster",
            "instances": 0,
            "name": "myapp",
            "node_args": [
                "--experimental-json-modules",
                "--gc_interval=100",
                "--max_old_space_size=512",
                "--optimize_for_size"
            ],
            "script": "./src/server/bin/www.mjs",
            "watch": true
        }
    ]
}
```

In package.json, I've specified a `scripts`-section:

```json
"scripts": {
    "start": "pm2 start ecosystem.json"
},
```

In the IDE, I've configured an **npm** script run configuration:

[image: npm run]

Now, when I click, **pm2** is started and shows a correct running processes summary:

[image: App [myapp] launched (4 instances)]

However, when I try to open an app in a browser (`127.0.0.1:3000` or `localhost:3000`), I get `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`, this site can’t be reached.

It looks like, the app doesn't listen for the port 3000 anymore.
How can I reach my app running in **pm2**?

P.S. Based on [Nodejs + expressjs - pm2 and forever don't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38159890/nodejs-expressjs-pm2-and-forever-dont-work), I've checked, I run `"script": "./src/server/bin/www.mjs"`, so I assume, **pm2** gets the proper path to the `bin/www.mjs`.

Comment: The config looks fine. Try to output to the console the port that the application will eventually listen to and look through the "pm2 logs".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After exploring the case more detailed, I get `ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ESM_URL_SCHEME` in the console. The root of the issue is on a side of **PM2**. The problem is that currently `"exec_mode": "cluster"` doesn't work, while `"exec_mode": "fork"` can be used without any issue.

For some reason, this [issue](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/4839) has been closed as solved, while in fact it seems like the fix has not been yet released.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue to this recently trying to spin up a web service using Express. After updating to the latest release of pm2, the issue has resolved. Looking at the [release notes for 5.3.0](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/releases/tag/5.3.0), it seems like the second bullet point is a PR that matches up to this error message.